# Approximation of a function using n intervals

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, approximation, linear-approximation, approximate-integration

Consider the function   =   and divide the domain 0 ≤  ≤ 1 into m intervals. For the “exact” approximation of the function, we will use  = 100 intervals.

Plot the “exact” function when  = 4. Then starting with  = 2 and increasing m gradually, plot the various approximations on the same plot as the exact function. How large must m be to discern the qualitative behavior of the exact function (i.e., have the same number of minima and maxima points)? Can you suggest a general criterion valid for any n that specifies the smallest m that still provides a qualitative approximation of the exact function?

Comment: In all the instances where you mention "exact function", are you referring to $\sin(n\pi x)$ or its approximation with $m=100$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem